# Reasonable way to get custom webpart properties via jsom?

Tags: 2013, client-object-model

I need to fetch some of the custom properties of my webpart from the front-end.
Currently, I'm using

```
var oFile = context.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath);
var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var webPartDefinitionCollection = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();
context.load(webPartDefinitionCollection);
context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var webPartDefinitions = [];
    var webParts = [];
    for (var i = 0, il = webPartDefinitionCollection.get_count(); i < il; i++) {
        webPartDefinitions[i] = webPartDefinitionCollection.get_item(i);
        context.load(webPartDefinitions[i]);
        webParts[i] = webPartDefinitions[i].get_webPart();
        context.load(webParts[i]);
        context.load(webParts[i].get_properties());
    }
    context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        //Store the results
    });
});
```

To fetch web parts and then later on I can

```
var getCustomProperties = function(webPart) {
    var clientObjectProperties = webPart.get_objectData().get_clientObjectProperties();
    var methodReturnObjects = clientObjectProperties.Properties.get_objectData().get_methodReturnObjects();
    var dict = methodReturnObjects.$m_dict;
    if (dict === null || dict === void 0) {
        debugger;
    }
    return dict;
}
```

To get custom properties. However, all of this is pretty darn hacky, but I've failed to find any documentation on what's the *right* way to get access to these.

The properties are defined in the webpart .cs file as follows:

```
[WebBrowsable(true),
WebDisplayName("Birthday list title"),
WebDescription(""),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
Category("Category")]
public string BirthdaysListTitle { get; set; }
```

Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Do you have the source code of the webpart?

Comment: @AmalHashim Yes, the webpart is very simple and barebones, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Hidden field to the page.

Then on the `Page_Load` event of the webpart, set the value of the hidden field to the webpart property value.

Now using JavaScript, handle the `document.ready` event and read the hidden field value.

**[Reading WebPart Properties using JSOM](http://almondlabs.com/blog/update-web-part-properties-csom/)**

```
//pass in the web part ID as a string (guid)
function getWebPartProperties(wpId) {
    var dfd = $j.Deferred();

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
    var oFile = clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath);
    var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    var collWebPart = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();

    clientContext.load(collWebPart);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
        var webPartDef = null;
        for (var x = 0; x < collWebPart.get_count() && !webPartDef; x++) {
            var temp = collWebPart.get_item(x);
            if (temp.get_id().toString() === wpId) {
                webPartDef = temp;
            }
        }
        if (!webPartDef) {
            dfd.reject("Web Part: " + wpId + " not found on page: " + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
            return;
        }

        var webPartProperties = webPartDef.get_webPart().get_properties();
        clientContext.load(webPartProperties);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
            dfd.resolve(webPartProperties, webPartDef, clientContext);
        }), Function.createDelegate(this, function () { dfd.reject("Failed to load web part properties"); }));
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, function () { dfd.reject("Failed to load web part collection"); }));

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Comment: While this is certainly a cleaner option, it's still not a pretty solution. So I take it there's no way to correctly query the webpart properties from jsom?

Comment: @Nit I am not sure. There might be ways to do it using JSOM, but that require a good amount of coding. The approach I suggested is a workaround to get the task done.

Comment: Thanks, reading the comments on the linked article I found a good solution: using `clientContext.load(collWebPart, 'Include(WebPart.Properties)');`.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution that I came across is to serialize the properties I'm interested in and insert them as a script.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = serializer.Serialize(properties);
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "MyPrefix = { Data: " + json + "};", true);
}
```

While this also doesn't answer the problem via jsom, at least the properties are available instantly in Javascript.